# Populate table by looping through array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a table where first `td` of each `tr`, starting with 2nd `tr`, has to be populated from an array with items inserted in the order they are in the array.

Here is an example of my JavaScript:

```
terms = [
     "term 1",
     "term 2",
     "term 3",
     "term 4",
]; 
var terms_length = terms.length;
var r = 1;
r++;
for (var t=0; t < terms_length; t++) {
    $("#termstable tr:nth-child(" + r + ") td:nth-child(1)").html(terms[t]);
}
```

As of right now, it's populating only 2nd `tr`'s `td` with last item of the array.

Comment: Why do you need the `r` variable? Just use `t + 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your `r` into the loop

```
terms = [
 "term 1",
 "term 2",
 "term 3",
 "term 4",
]; 

var terms_length = terms.length;
var r = 1;
for (var t=0; t < terms_length; t++) {
    $("#termstable tr:nth-child(" + r + ") td:nth-child(1)").html(terms[t]);
    r++;
}
```

Comment: Yep. That works! Thank you! Can accept answer in 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing the variable `r` in the loop. `r` gets set to `1` incremented to `2` when `r++` runs then never changes

So in every loop the jquery would end up being

```
$("#termstable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").html(terms[t]);
```

You need to increment `r` in the loop as well.

```
terms = [
     "term 1",
     "term 2",
     "term 3",
     "term 4",
]; 
var terms_length = terms.length;
var r = 1;

for (var t=0; t < terms_length; t++) {
    $("#termstable tr:nth-child(" + r + ") td:nth-child(1)").html(terms[t]);
    r++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be quite a lot easier if you just use a little more jQuery

```
var terms = [
   "term 1",
   "term 2",
   "term 3",
   "term 4" 
]; 

$("#termstable tr:nth-child(n+2) td:first-child").html(function(i) {
    return terms[i];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment your `r` variable in the loop, using `++r` instead of `r`. But it is more simple to simply use `t + 2` and remove `r`. See this live demo:

```js
const terms = [
 "term 1",
 "term 2",
 "term 3",
 "term 4",
]; 

for (let t = 0; t < terms.length; t++) {
  $("#termstable tr:nth-child(" + (t + 2) + ") td:nth-child(1)").html(terms[t]);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="termstable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>term</th><th>#</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```